# I want to update multiple model fields at the same time in Django

Tags: python, django

I want to update all the marks fields from the form.py module:
so Can anyone suggest me the best way for updating all the marks fileds at a time.

**Views.py**

```py
def marks_view(request, roll_number):
   return render(request, 'marks_entry.html')
```

**Models.py**

```py
class NurseryResult(models.Model):
    roll_number = models.PositiveIntegerField(primary_key=True)
    student_name = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=False)
    academic_Year = models.CharField(blank=True, max_length=50)
    nepali = models.PositiveIntegerField( blank=True)
    nepali_gpa = models.FloatField( blank=True)
    nepali_grade = models.CharField( blank=True, max_length=50)
    english = models.PositiveIntegerField( blank=True)
    english_gpa = models.FloatField(blank=True)
    english_grade = models.CharField(blank=True, max_length=25)
    math = models.PositiveIntegerField(blank=True)
    math_gpa = models.FloatField(blank=True)
    math_grade = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=True)
    science = models.PositiveIntegerField(blank=True)
    science_gpa = models.FloatField(blank=True)
    science_grade = models.CharField(max_length=10, blank=True)
    oral_nepali = models.PositiveIntegerField(blank=True)
    oral_nepali_gpa = models.FloatField(blank=True)
    oral_nepali_grade = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=True)
    oral_math = models.PositiveIntegerField(blank=True)
    oral_math_gpa = models.FloatField(blank=True)
    oral_math_grade = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=True)
    oral_english = models.PositiveIntegerField(blank=True)
    oral_english_gpa = models.FloatField(blank=True)
    oral_english_grade = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=True)
    hygiene = models.PositiveIntegerField(blank=True)
    hygiene_gpa = models.FloatField(blank=True)
    hygiene_grade = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=True)
    grade = models.CharField(max_length=10, blank=True)
    gpa = models.FloatField(blank=True)
```

Comment: It's in a single model, use Django model forms.

Comment: yes. it is in a same model and wanna let a user to display the data previous data and provide a dacility to update it.

Comment: Do you mean one by one?

Comment: no all at a time.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Django [`forms`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/forms/modelforms/#django.forms.ModelForm)([`ModelForm`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/forms/modelforms/#django.forms.ModelForm) class),

```
class NurseryResultForm(forms.ModelForm):

    class Meta:
       model = NurseryResult
       fields = '__all__' # fields you need in form
       exclude = [...]    # fields you don't need in form(if fields = '__all__')
```

your views.py

```
def marks_view(request, roll_number):
    # if this is a POST request we need to process the form data
    if request.method == 'POST':
        # create a form instance and populate it with data from the request:
        form = NurseryResult(request.POST)
        # check whether it's valid:
        if form.is_valid():
            # process the data in form.cleaned_data as required
            # ...
            # redirect to a new URL:
            return HttpResponseRedirect('/url/')

    # if a GET (or any other method) we'll create a blank form
    # or fill the form with query object
    else:
        form = NurseryResultForm()

    return render(request, 'your_temlate.html', {'form': form})
```

This is a general implementation. It will be better if you read the [doc](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/forms/) first.

Comment: I want to update the all marks fields at a time. And display the data that is already stored in the database using instance.

Comment: Add your fields into `fields` like a list or tuple or you can add `__all__` and exclude the unnecessary ones. Update can be done using the same approach. Pass the query object to `NurseryResultForm()` in `get()` to display object for a roll number